# Android SQLiteOpenHelper: error code = 1, msg = near "create": syntax error

Tags: android, database, sqliteopenhelper

this is my code to create database table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inizio creazione database MessagesDB");
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE2 + " (" + Key_key + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + Key_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + Key_author + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
+ Key_date_create + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Key_sender + " TEXT, " 
+ Key_date_sent + " TEXT, " + Key_recipient + " TEXT, " 
+ Key_date_received + " TEXT, " + Key_message + " TEXT, " 
+ Key_message_path + " TEXT, " + Key_size + " INTEGER" + ");";  
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE); 
            Log.i(TAG, "Creazione database MessagesDB avvenuta con successo");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Errore nella create table messages", e);
        }   
}
```

but I have an error in the logcat:

```
:Errore nella create table messages
:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "create": syntax error: CREATE TABLE messagesDB (_key TEXT PRIMARY KEY, _id INTEGER NOT NULL, author TEXT NOT NULL, date create TEXT NOT NULL, sender TEXT, date_sent TEXT, recipient TEXT, date_received TEXT, message TEXT, message_path TEXT, size INTEGER);
```

I don't understand why this error.
Could someone help me to understand?
(sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `create` from `date create TEXT NOT NULL`. You seem to have added it by mistake.

Looks like `Key_date_create` has the value `date create`, maybe you meant `date_create`?